# Methods For Selective (or Ranked) Chatbot

Tags: nlp, chatbot

I am about to create chatbot with NLP or DNN's method. The chatbot is about to reply user's sentence based on a knowledgebase (maybe in a database).

I found LSA/PLSA can be used, but I want to explore any further methods I can use except that. Recently, I was looking for some methods and found that DSSM (Deep Structured Semantic Model) can be an alternative. Is this the method I can use or might you suggest me any methods I can use?

By the way, after reading some articles about DSSM, I have misconception about negative samples when training DSSM. If you are about to suggest me with DSSM, please help me to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think we have any DSSM platforms available for general use to us as chatbot developers, just yet.

At least not like the [currently available language interpreter platforms](https://www.cmswire.com/customer-experience/top-14-chatbot-building-platforms-of-2017/)
(Like IBM Watson, Microsoft LUIS).

I would suggest starting with one of the popular platforms available now and continuing research / watching for [developments in deep learning](https://dzone.com/articles/chatbots-with-machine-learning-building-neural-con).